# WebAPI Switch database Collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using Mongodb with c# driver.

The general question is, how can one user switch collection through api calls without affecting other users.

All the collections are in the same Database, the call goes through controller to service class, if I switch the IMongoCollection in the service, it also affects other users since the service is injected during the Startup and there is only one service running for the controller.

Or is it reasonable to create a new service instance for each call from the endpoint? If so, how would the implementation be?

Hope the issue is described clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Can the service be injected in scope level so that `IMongoCollection` is injected with appropriate collection?

Answer (score 1):

actually the solution to the problem is simple, you need to create more than one setting to read it yourself. Whichever database you want to trade, you can use it on your own terms.

add appsettings.json ->

```
"MongoConnection1": {
    "ConnectionStringMongo": "connectionstring",
    "Database": "your_collection1"
  },
  "MongoConnection2": {
    "ConnectionStringMongo": "connectionstring",
    "Database": "your_collection2"
  },
```

And

```
 //add startup.cs service
   services.Configure<YourSettingClass>(options =>
   {
    //YourSettingClass property = ConnectionStringMongo,Database
       options.ConnectionStringMongo
            = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection1:ConnectionStringMongo").Value;
       options.Database
            = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection1:Database").Value;
       //Or add a list database property
       //options.ConnectionStringMongo
       //= Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection2:ConnectionStringMongo").Value;
       //options.Database.Add(Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection1:Database").Value);
       //options.Database.Add(Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection2:Database").Value); 
   });
```

And use mongoContext class:)

```
public MongoContext(IOptions<YourSettingClass> settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionStringMongo);
            if (client != null)
                _database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
        }
```

Edit1:
I understand you, in fact, let's assume that the client that does this is changing an application setting.
Suppose you set a default connection and database.
When Clint makes changes, your connection and database information to be read in a static class will now change.
From now on, the next requests will be on this channel.

```
public static class ConnetionInformation
    {
        public static string connectionString = "MongoConnection1:ConnectionStringMongo";
        public static string connectionDatabase = "MongoConnection1:ConnectionStringMongo";

        public static void setConnection(string _connectionString, string _connectionDatabase)
        {
            connectionString = _connectionString;
            connectionDatabase = _connectionDatabase;
        }
    }
    
public MongoContext(ConnetionInformation _connetionInformation,IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            
            var client = new MongoClient(_configuration[_connetionInformation.connectionString]);
            if (client != null)
                _database = client.GetDatabase(_connetionInformation.connectionDatabase);
        }
        
        //exapmle set 
        ConnetionInformation.setConnection("MongoConnection2:ConnectionStringMongo","MongoConnection2:ConnectionStringMongo");
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion! Though I don' fully understand your solution (especially where the mongoContext resides), it seems to me that it switches between collections when we start the webAPI. What I hope to achieve is that user can switch from the client side. Say a user use URI call "Project01/objects" to access the collection of Project01.Objects, while not affacting other user.

Comment: Will it be switched by the client?

Comment: Yes, it will switched by the client~

Comment: user2922475 set answer check please :)